# Проблема с библиотекой NumPy в Python 3.5: time.time() ведёт к AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-import

Установила библиотеку NumPy, запускала элементарный код из учебника, например

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(a.ndim)
print(a.shape)
```

все работало корректно 
после попытки запуска

```
import timeit
normal_py_sec = timeit.timeit('sum(x*x for x in range(1000))',
number=10000)
naive_np_sec = timeit.timeit(
'sum(na*na)',
setup="import numpy as np; na=np.arange(1000)",
number=10000)
good_np_sec = timeit.timeit(
'na.dot(na)',
setup="import numpy as np; na=np.arange(1000)",
number=10000)
print("Normal Python: %f sec" % normal_py_sec)
print("Naive NumPy: %f sec" % naive_np_sec)
```

выдало ошибку. Теперь каждый запуск любого кода с использованием NumPy крашится на первой же строчке импорта, выдавая

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oksana/PycharmProjects/machine_learning/ch_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    _startTime = time.time()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Переустановка через pip3 и yum не помогли. Проверяла в Python 2, там проблем нет. Сама в Python новичок, буду очень признательна за помощь.

Comment: В теме вопроса вы указали Python 3.5 а в Traceback: `python3.4` - вы уверены, что у вас все в порядке с окружением (UNIX environment)?

Comment: На англоязычном SO был похожий вопрос ([ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886712/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-timeit-while-doing-timeit-a-p)).

Comment: прошу прощения, перепутала, на windows просто 3.5, здесь 3.4

Comment: Да похоже extraenough прав(а), только в вашем случае это не стандартный (т.е. ваш) `time.py`...

Answer (score 2):

разобралась, проблема в том, что я второй файл назвала time.py

Comment: Это распространённая ошибка. Лучше не давать глобальным модулям имена конфликтующие со стандартной библиотекой, [ещё пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299371/converting-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python-3-4#comment39430758_25299371). Чтобы python не пытался из текущей директории импортировать, можно его запускать как `python -I`.